# React Native + Redux: Form to edit own profile

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

How can I pre-fill form fields with my own profile values?

ie. see my First Name, Last Name and Email fields populated on my Setting's page, so I could change them if needed.

Here are the relevant code, in case it would help.

### Call to action:

```
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

<Button onPress={ () => { Actions.profileEdit(); } } />
```

### ProfileEdit:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ProfileForm from './ProfileForm';

componentWillMount() {
  this.props.profileFetch()

  _.each(this.props.profile, (value, prop) => {
    this.props.profileUpdate({ prop, value });
  })
}

onButtonPress() {
  const { firstName, lastName, email } = this.props;

  this.props.profileSave({ firstName, lastName, email });
}

class ProfileEdit extends Component {
  render() {
    <ProfileForm {...this.props} />

    <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
      <Text>Save Changes</Text>
    </Button>
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { firstName, lastName, email } = state.profileForm;

  return { firstName, lastName, email };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { profileFetch, profileSave, profileUpdate })(ProfileEdit);
```

### ProfileForm:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { profileUpdate } from '../../actions';

class ProfileForm extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Form>
        <Input
          placeholder="First Name"
          value={this.props.firstName}
          onChangeText={value => this.props.profileUpdate({ prop: 'firstName', value })}
        />
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { firstName, lastName, email } = state.profileForm;

  return { firstName, lastName, email };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { profileUpdate })(ProfileForm);
```

### ProfileActions:

```
export const profileFetch = () => {
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();

  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/profile`)
      .on('value', (snapshot) => {
        dispatch({ type: PROFILE_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: snapshot.val() });
      });
  };
};

export const profileSave = ({ firstName, lastName, email }) => {
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();

  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/profile`)
      .set({ firstName, lastName, email })
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({ type: PROFILE_SAVE_SUCCESS });
        Actions.profileEdit({ type: 'reset' });
      });
  };
};

export const profileUpdate = ({ prop, value }) => {
  return {
    type: PROFILE_UPDATE,
    payload: { prop, value }
  };
};
```

### ProfileFormReducer:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  email: ''
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PROFILE_UPDATE:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.prop]: action.payload.value };
    case PROFILE_SAVE_SUCCESS:
      return INITIAL_STATE;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

### ProfileReducer:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PROFILE_FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`defaultValue` for TextInput is what you're looking for ([docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#defaultvalue)). This will provide an initial value but once the user starts typing the value will be overwritten.

Looking at your ProfileForm this should do what you want

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { profileUpdate } from '../../actions';

class ProfileForm extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Form>
        <Input
          placeholder="First Name"
          defaultValue={this.props.firstName}
          onChangeText={value => this.props.profileUpdate({ prop: 'firstName', value })}
        />
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { firstName, lastName, email } = state.profileForm;

  return { firstName, lastName, email };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { profileUpdate })(ProfileForm);
```

Comment: Hey @SpencerCarli, thanks for your reply, but `this.props.firstName` is empty. Here is the output for `this.props`: `{"firstName":"","lastName":"","email":""}`. And after 2-3 seconds, I get those values from Firebase via profileFetch: `{"email":"John@doe.com","firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"}`. Think it's something related to `async` via Redux-Thunk.

Comment: @AndrePereira Are you asking how to avoid the wait for data? If so check out the package redux-persist. Otherwise, you might want to wait and show a loading indicator while you're making the remote request.